# Why won't this java class print the object?

Tags: java, class, oop, object

Here is my first class rightTriangle

```
public class rightTriangle {
    private double sideA;
    private double sideB;

    public double getSideA() {
        return sideA;
    }

    public void changeSideA(double sideA) {
        if (sideA > 0)
            sideA = 4;
    }

    public void changeSideB(double sideB) {
        if (sideB > 0)
            sideB = 9;
    }

    public double getSideB() {
        return sideB;
    }

    public rightTriangle(double a, double b) {
        sideA = a;
        sideB = b;
    }

    public rightTriangle() {
        sideA=0;
        sideB=0;
    }

//START METHODS

    public double getHypotenuse(double sideA, double sideB) {
        double sideASquared, sideBSquared, discriminant, hypotenuse;

        sideASquared = sideA * sideA;
        sideBSquared = sideB * sideB;

        discriminant = sideASquared + sideBSquared;

        hypotenuse = Math.sqrt(discriminant);
        return hypotenuse;
    }

    public double getAngleA(double sideB, double hypotenuse){
        double angleA = Math.asin(sideB/hypotenuse);
        Math.toDegrees(angleA);
        return angleA;
    }

    public double getAngleB(double sideA, double hypotenuse){
        double angleB = Math.asin(sideA/hypotenuse);
        Math.toDegrees(angleB);
        return angleB;
    }

    public double getPerimeter(double sideA, double sideB) {
        double perimeter = (sideA + sideB + getHypotenuse(sideA,sideB));
        return perimeter;
    }

    public double getArea(double sideA, double sideB) {
        double area = (sideA * sideB * .5);
        return area;
    }

    public String toString() {
        //String stringA, stringB, stringC, stringPer, stringArea;
        return ("Side A is " + sideA + "." + " Side B is " + sideB + "." +
                " Side C is " + getHypotenuse(sideA,sideB) + "." + "\n" +
                "The perimeter is " + getPerimeter(sideA,sideB) + "." +
                "The area is " + getArea(sideA, sideB) + ".");   
    }    
}
```

Then here is my user class that creates the objects in the class.

```
public class user {
    rightTriangle triangle1 = new rightTriangle(5,20);
    rightTriangle triangle2 = new rightTriangle(3,4);
    rightTriangle triangle3 = new rightTriangle();
    rightTriangle triangle4 = new rightTriangle(16.3,4.889);

    public void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(triangle2);
    }
}
```

However, when I  print a triangle object in the console, lets say triangle2 is not getting printed. Why?

**UPDATE**

**This was solved by placing my object creations under the main method in the user class.**

Final looks like this:

```
public class user {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    rightTriangle triangle1 = new rightTriangle(5,20);
    rightTriangle triangle2 = new rightTriangle(3,4);
    rightTriangle triangle3 = new rightTriangle();
    rightTriangle triangle4 = new rightTriangle(16.3,4.889);


        System.out.println(triangle2);
    }
}
```

Comment: What output do you get?

Comment: What is the output now?

Comment: I run it and nothing is printed. No error. Just blank white space.

Comment: How exactly do you run it?

Comment: Yeah I don't see anything wrong with the code itself. Could it be your IDE?

Comment: where is your main method?

Comment: Im using eclipse and just run the program as always.

Comment: Are you sure you're not running a different class with another `main` method?

Comment: My main method is in the user class

Comment: Here let me check.

Comment: than you should add static keyword

Comment: I'm pretty sure Im running the right class there are only two files and one is user.java and the other is rightTriangle.java

Comment: and adding static shows the error "cannot make reference to nonstatic filed triangle2"

Comment: Maybe try placing the objects in the main method?

Comment: Ok I moved the files over and now it says unable to launch and there are no recent launches?

Comment: And this is off topic, but you should use PascalCase when naming your classes and use camelCase when naming methods and variables.

Answer (score 4):

Since is not possible **to make reference to nonstatic filed** you can not do this, and this code is not running nor compiling:

```
public class user {
    rightTriangle triangle1 = new rightTriangle(5,20);
    ...
    public void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(triangle1);
    }
}
```

Fix it by moving the object in the main method

## Example:

```
  public class user {
        public void main(String[] args) {
            rightTriangle triangle1 = new rightTriangle(5,20);
            System.out.println(triangle1);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

**The static method can not use non static data member or call non-static method directly**.

You have to make either instance variable static or to place them in main method

```
    public class user {
    static rightTriangle triangle1 = new rightTriangle(5,20);
    static rightTriangle triangle2 = new rightTriangle(3,4);
    static rightTriangle triangle3 = new rightTriangle();
    static rightTriangle triangle4 = new rightTriangle(16.3,4.889);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(triangle2);
    }
}
```

or

```
    public class user {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        rightTriangle triangle1 = new rightTriangle(5,20);
        rightTriangle triangle2 = new rightTriangle(3,4);
        rightTriangle triangle3 = new rightTriangle();
        rightTriangle triangle4 = new rightTriangle(16.3,4.889);
        System.out.println(triangle2);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need user class

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    rightTriangle triangle1 = new rightTriangle(5,20);
    rightTriangle triangle2 = new rightTriangle(3,4);
    rightTriangle triangle3 = new rightTriangle();
    rightTriangle triangle4 = new rightTriangle(16.3,4.889);

    System.out.println(triangle2);
}
```

**N.B.** `System.out.println(object)` means that the will be executed the toString() method defined on your object (ovveride), otherwise it would be executed the default toString() method:

```
getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())
```

That is something like `rightTriangle@15db9742`
Therefore, pay attention and remember to overrides toString method, else you can print the single values using getters

At last, use capital letter for naming your classes, according to Java code conventions:

```
public class RightTriangle { ... }
```

So:

```
RightTriangle rightTriangle1 = new RightTriangle();
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your user class with this,

```
public class user {
    static rightTriangle triangle1 = new rightTriangle(5,20);
    static rightTriangle triangle2 = new rightTriangle(3,4);
    static rightTriangle triangle3 = new rightTriangle();
    static rightTriangle triangle4 = new rightTriangle(16.3,4.889);

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        System.out.println(triangle2);
    }


}
```

add static in main method and use static variable traingle 2

Answer (score 0):

you can override toString method in RightTriangle Class which will be called after `System.out.println(triangle2);`